# character set mismatch COALESCE

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Hola tengo un problma con esta consulta, me dice el error

```
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NCHAR got NUMBER
00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error en la línea: 54, columna: 43
```

Creo que el problema es porque debo castear el 10 o algo asi, probe con este post [Post 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23490330/ora-12704-character-set-mismatch-with-nvarchar2-datatype-in-oracle)
agregandole n'' adelante del 10 pero no funciono porque el codigo se pone azul.
tambien probé con este [Post 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15967201/ora-12704-character-set-mismatch) que dice que hay que agregar un  N'' || antes del 10 y pasa lo mismo...

```
SELECT NOMBRE, COALESCE(DIRECCION,CORREO, 10) comm
FROM ESTUDIANTE
WHERE GENERO_A =   
   (SELECT GENERO_A
    FROM ESTUDIANTE
    GROUP BY GENERO_A
    HAVING COUNT(GENERO_A) = 
        (SELECT MAX(COUNT(*)) as CONTAR
        FROM ESTUDIANTE
        GROUP BY GENERO_A))
ORDER BY NOMBRE;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te propongo 2 posibles soluciones:

## Con N''

Dices que estás poniendo N'' delante del 10, pero no es delante(`N''10`), sino con el 10 en medio, así:
`N'10'`. No sé si has probado esto, pero te lo pongo por si acaso dado que tu en tu pregunta me haces pensar que no has caído en ese detalle.

## Usando la función CAST de oracle

Ejemplo simple:

```
SELECT CAST (miles AS INT)
FROM Flights
```

Más info de esta función [aquí](http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rrefsqlj33562.html).

Espero que te sirva.

Comment: Si gracias, prbe de las 2 formas y en las 2 me funciona ahora, solo que el codigo me lo pone todo en azul desde la posicion de donde pongo el N'10' hasta el final como si todo fuera una cadena (aunque funciona bien) y con el CAST ya no se produce eso, yo creo que es problema del sql developer...